# qt4 Clipboard error on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: qt4, clipboard, canopy, notimplementedexception, pyface

Trying to run an external program that uses the python backend and after having installed the canopy package (after also trying the 'manual' pyface builds) I keep getting a weird and seemingly very basic error. Any suggestions would be most welcome!

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/melview", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('melview==1.0', 'console_scripts', 'melview')()

  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 351, in load_entry_point
    return get_distribution(dist).load_entry_point(group, name)

  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 2363, in load_entry_point
    return ep.load()

  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 2088, in load
    entry = __import__(self.module_name, globals(),globals(), ['__name__'])

  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/melview/melodic_traits.py", line 42, in <module>

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyface-4.4.0-py2.7.egg/pyface/api.py", line 19, in <module>
    from clipboard import clipboard, Clipboard

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyface-4.4.0-py2.7.egg/pyface/clipboard.py", line 23, in <module>
    clipboard = Clipboard()

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyface-4.4.0-py2.7.egg/pyface/toolkit.py", line 92, in __init__
    raise NotImplementedError("the %s pyface backend doesn't implement %s" % (ETSConfig.toolkit, oname))

NotImplementedError: the qt4 pyface backend doesn't implement Clipboard
```

Answer (score 2):

This answer may be quite late for you but posting here for everyone's benefit.

This issue is mainly because of a missing "traitsui" dependency in pyface setup.py script. You can workaround this by manually installing traitsui.